# Find combinations in Scala List of Lists

Tags: scala

I have a `List[List[Row]]` (Row is a custom type, it's definition is not important here).

I want to get all the possible ways that I can select a single Row from each inner List so that the result is also a `List[List[Row]]`.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @vidit I've played around with for comprehensions and the List.combinations method, but I'm struggling to generate the combinations across multiple Lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> def combs[A](xss: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = xss match {
     |   case Nil => List(Nil)
     |   case xs::rss => for(x <- xs;cs <- combs(rss)) yield x::cs
     | }
combs: [A](xss: List[List[A]])List[List[A]]

scala> combs(List(List(1, 2), List(4, 5), List(6))) foreach println
List(1, 4, 6)
List(1, 5, 6)
List(2, 4, 6)
List(2, 5, 6)
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this solution is not tail recursive. So if your outer list is longer than your stack can handle, you will get a StackOverflow exception thrown at runtime. 
`combs((1 to 10000).toList.map(_ => List(1)))` produces `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425930/generating-all-possible-combinations-from-a-listlistint-in-scala