# Nested Looping over dynamic list of list in scala

Tags: scala, loops, nested

I have list of list which will be generated dynamically based on data.I want to pair nested elements like this

```
Input 1: 
var y :List[List[String]] = List(List (1, 2), List(3, 4))
For this output should be 

List[(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]

Input :2
var y :List[List[String]] = List(List (1, 2), List(3, 4),List(6,7),List(8))
For this output should be 

List[(1,3,6,8),(1,3,7,8),(1,4,6,8),(1,4,7,8),(2,3,6,8),(2,3,7,8),(2,4,6,8),(2,4,7,8)]
```

If i know all lists in advance I can do something like below.

```
val a = List ("month=1", "month=2")
val b = List ("date=3", "date=4")

for(a1 <- a; b1 <- b)
    println(a1 +','+ b1 )
```

But how do I generate expected output if number of input list are unknown during compile time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425930/generating-all-possible-combinations-from-a-listlistint-in-scala

Comment: Tried suggested link.For large data set that solution is taking long time.

Comment: Did you look at the `Stream` implementation at the bottom of the answer?